# I'm currently doing a unity 3d combat course and i'm stuck on this

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

This won't go away now matter what i try, even though i have done everything according to the course i'm following.

'Inputreader' does not implement interface member 'Controls.IPlayerActions.OnDodge(InputAction.CallbackContext)'

Here is the code

```
public class Inputreader : MonoBehaviour, Controls.IPlayerActions
{

    private Controls controls;

    public event Action jumpEvent;

    public event Action DodgeEvent;


    private void Start()
    {
        Controls = new Controls();
        Controls.Player.setCallbacks(this);

        Controls.Player.Enable();
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        Controls.Player.Disable();
    }

    public void onJump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        if (context.preformed)
        {
            jumpEvent?.Invoke();
        }

    }

    public void onDodge(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        if (context.preformed)
        {
            DodgeEvent?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried renaming "onDodge" to "OnDodge"? This error specifies that the class doesn't implement a method of the interface you are implementing correctly. If I look at the error, "OnDodge" is spelled with a capital O. (Probably the same error for OnJump).

Comment: As @Tristan T noted, consistent title case on your method names would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let's get started with understanding the error, as that is the most important part of the problem.

```
'Inputreader' does not implement interface member 'Controls.IPlayerActions.OnDodge(InputAction.CallbackContext)'
```

What does this mean?

Let's start at the beginnning: The class `InputReader` apparently doesn't implement something. Why does it have to implement something?

Well, that is because of this line:

```cs
public class Inputreader : MonoBehaviour, Controls.IPlayerActions {
```

What does this line mean? It means that the class InputReader will have (Implement) all required methods and properties of the Interfaces/Classes `MonoBehavior` and `Controls.IPlayerActions`

In this case, `IPlayerActions` specify the following requirements:

1. Must have a public method `OnJump` which accepts `InputAction.CallbackContext context` as a parameter.
2. Must have a public method `onDodge(InputAction.CallbackContext context)` with the same sort of parameter.

Now back to the error, it specifies that this class is missing an implementation for `OnDodge`. Please note that everything in c# is case-sensitive. What does this mean?

`public void onDodge` is not the same as `public void OnDodge`.
What does the error specify?
`Controls.IPlayerActions."OnDodge"`. What did you implement in your class? `"onDodge"`. Do you see the difference?

Make sure the capitalization is correct for all implemented class members, or else you will get such errors.